# how can I design sidebar using bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, sidebar

I'm trying to make sidebar in my application, but I have no idea on how to use `col` to separate each content to be on `left`, `right` and `center`.

This is my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'register' %}"><h2>Borinati</h2></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'FeedBack' %}">About</a></li>                      
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the content i want to be on `left`:

```
<a href="">Home</a>
<a href="">Contact Us</a>
<a href="">Companies</a>
<a href="">Products</a>
<a href="">Our Partner</a>
<a href="">Our Sponsor</a>
```

And this is the content I want to be on `center`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <form action="" method="GET">
        <input placeholder="Search By Category" type="text" class="form-control" name="q">
    </form>
   </div>
  </div> 
  <br>
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        {% for question in news reversed %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card my-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="{% url 'view-News' news.slug %}" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    {{news.title}}
                    </a><br>
                    <br>
                    <a href="{% url 'Public_Profile' news.user.profile.slug %}">
                        {{news.user.username}}
                    </a>
                    <br>
                    <p class="btn btn-primary disabled btn-sm">{{news.category}}</p>                            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try, this is example how can you create bootstap 5 sidebar toggle
https://codepen.io/truongtx-ccvn/pen/qLXGKV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 1-1 almost official example from https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/.
I can do a copy paste, and I will, but I suggest you try also.

I also pasted your HTML into it.

```js
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar v6.0.5 (https://startbootstrap.com/template/simple-sidebar)
 * Copyright 2013-2022 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

// 
// Scripts
// 
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  // Toggle the side navigation
  const sidebarToggle = document.body.querySelector('#sidebarToggle');
  if (sidebarToggle) {
    sidebarToggle.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.body.classList.toggle('sb-sidenav-toggled');

    })
  };
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

body.sb-sidenav-toggled #wrapper #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  body.sb-sidenav-toggled #wrapper #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>


  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar-->
    <div class="border-end bg-white" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading border-bottom bg-light">Start Bootstrap</div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="#!">Dashboard</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="#!">Shortcuts</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="#!">Overview</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="#!">Events</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="#!">Profile</a>
        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3" href="#!">Status</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content wrapper-->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">



      <!-- Top navigation-->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'register' %}">
            <h2>Borinati</h2>
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'FeedBack' %}">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>


      <!-- Page content-->
      <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <form action="" method="GET">
        <input placeholder="Search By Category" type="text" class="form-control" name="q">
    </form>
   </div>
  </div> 
  <br>
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        {% for question in news reversed %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card my-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="{% url 'view-News' news.slug %}" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    {{news.title}}
                    </a><br>
                    <br>
                    <a href="{% url 'Public_Profile' news.user.profile.slug %}">
                        {{news.user.username}}
                    </a>
                    <br>
                    <p class="btn btn-primary disabled btn-sm">{{news.category}}</p>                            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
</body>
```

Comment: This is how it look like sir: [Image](https://scontent.fabv2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/292792380_144472041582522_5860604738391100132_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_p180x540&_nc_cat=102&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_eui2=AeG1P3gRyQTbDWFjHHb-EG7R8mwntWD9iSLybCe1YP2JIuu6zqHYGtCeekScUo3ue7U4Mnd39V2cT3eBJaPniGCX&_nc_ohc=8GmufAWdTMYAX-uX7mF&_nc_zt=23&_nc_ht=scontent.fabv2-1.fna&oh=00_AT9jFc3ktz69qzGaiYKy7qzo7Bz6pUHruFWdsuQOcLBfnA&oe=62D763F5)

Comment: this is how it look like on mobile sir: [image](https://scontent.fabv2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/293328912_144472901582436_7508199931023142225_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_p180x540&_nc_cat=109&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_eui2=AeFOqRfjukoO7g88RehsFfWo7IMo7JyyG4LsgyjsnLIbgny63Uufm95-brGHZeROwCYKIMHQ_woOyM39XCeI_dZW&_nc_ohc=4Rp0qeHBw9cAX-XLlu4&_nc_zt=23&_nc_ht=scontent.fabv2-2.fna&oh=00_AT8jdw1ZQhXqWBLzmwtZ8ywFohMSBu5IBh4t6lkbmwHz6w&oe=62D7122D)

Comment: I have try to use the same method above, but it doesn't work, that's why I'm asking for help here sir. I thought it is because of the lack of knowledge I have with `Bootstrap` but it doesn't,

Comment: But this is what my snippet does. Did you look at it? (Also Full page)

Comment: I think the method is broken or something went wrong in my applications, but it doesn't, it Is because the sidebar was build using `react` while I'm using Django

Comment: Yes, it is working fine on Stack Overflow code snippet, but I don't know why it is not working in my machine.

Comment: I have edited this question, please edit your answer.